# The VS 2012 Update 2 installation hang at the beginning

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm installing VS2012 update 2, but now whenever I tried to install, the installation hang at the beginning while applying "Microsoft Portable Library Multi-Target Pack" and not able to progress at all. I'm running Windows 8 x64 with latest updates and VS2012 Ultimate.

Anyone encountered the same situation? Anyone got it working?

BTW, I have 2 win8 x64 machines, both have this issue.

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com for help.  They will need the installer log files.  You'll find them in your TEMP directory, their name starts with dd_vsupdate_kb2707250.  Try to recover the machine, if necessary, from the restore point that was created at install startup.

Comment: Thx, will try that. Let's hope it just works.